# Ubuntu16.04: Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu-16.04

At the beginning, I install R-3.2 in the ubuntu 16.04 by the command: sudo apt-get install r-base. But I want to update the R to R.3.4. I followed the instruction to update my my R as the following link:https://askubuntu.com/questions/909689/upgrading-r-version-3-3-in-ubuntu-16-04.

After I updated my R to R-3.4, and I run the command: R, but there is error:

```
 Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'
```

But after I run the command: sudo R,  there is no error, and I can enter into the R environment.

and the df output is:

```
~$ df
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev            132052640         0  132052640   0% /dev
tmpfs            26414104      9376   26404728   1% /run
/dev/sda1        15348720  14618356          0 100% /
tmpfs           132070516       108  132070408   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           132070516         0  132070516   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1      2064113824 520939540 1438300352  27% /data
tmpfs            26414104        12   26414092   1% /run/user/111
tmpfs            26414104         0   26414104   0% /run/user/2098
```

Could you tell me how to solve this issue, I mean I just want to run the command: R to enter the environment.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the output from a `df` call?

Comment: thanks I have updated my question

Comment: I've often seen error in creating "R_TempDir" when I'm out of available disk space for the appropriate parent directory. Could that be the case with /dev/sda1? I'd recommend clearing up some space and trying again.

Comment: hi thanks for your comments, could you tell me how to clearn up some space /sda1

Comment: Just moving/deleting files. If there are old/unused tmp files stored there by R, I'd start with those.

Comment: Your main system drive is full. I don't think we can help you make more space, but if you are inexperienced with system management on Linux don't go deleting anything as root (via sudo) that you don't understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a "my disk is full" problem" and user needs to sort that out themselves.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I have no Linux management experience, could you tell me in detail how to do it, but why I used sudo R is ok?

Comment: please don't vote to off-topic!

Comment: I think there are better sites on stack exchange to help you with cleaning up your disk (try the ubuntu site of superuser).  You might find out you had a core dump or something but this is really not the place for it.